# How to increase the MySQL variable count

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jtable

Friends, in my project I have a variable named **bill_number**; every time the *PRINT* bill button is clicked I want to increase the value of **bill_number** by one in the database. Please help me as soon as possible.

```
set @bill_number = @bill_numer+1;
```

This is the query I've tried before but it's not working.

Comment: Well thats setting a variable, setting it in a table would require a table....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise to maintain a `table` containing all the counts (like bill_number) and then use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` to fetch and update the count on the events. It will increase the maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues. First you need to initialize @bill_number.

```
set @bill_number = 0;
```

Next you made a typo and called it `bill_numer` instead of `bill_number`:

```
set @bill_number = @bill_number+1;
```

Comment: ... and the typo part?  You should have included the relevant code... you can't initialize a number to null... null is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works well, but I think that you didn't set the initial value for the variable so the result will be null+1 = null 
the result always will be null.
Some where in your code there must be a place that you decide to set the initial value for the variable like:

```
set @bill_number = 0;
```

then your code will work fine.
I hope that will help you.

Comment: you can't initialize the variable to null because adding the null to a number will result as null as I mentioned in my answer:
NULL + NUMBER -------> NULL
,you have to initialize it to a number like zero or -1 ...

Comment: thans,but i have initialized it to zero.

Comment: set @bill_number = 0;
but while i select than in database it shows null.

Comment: I assume you are trying to access that variable from another transaction in which you didn't initialize the variable or even declare, 
when you declare a variable so you gotta initialize it and use it in the same transaction...

Comment: ZORRO_BLANCO, thank you for your reply....
I have figured out that every time i close the mysql...the variable reset into null..how can i avoid this...and help me in how can i set BIGINT as signed to a varible in table

Comment: My pleasure, and Yes, this is what I am talking about, every time you close MySQL it opens a new transaction, now the other part of your question about the BIGINT is not clear to me, in my sql "bigint" data type is just "int", I assume you want to set a field equals a variable, lets say we have a table [Bills] with an int field [Number] and you want to set it:
--start query--
UPDATE Bills AS b, 
 (SELECT @ bill_number:=@ bill_number +1 rownum, id, number
        FROM Bills, (select @ bill_number := 0) rn) AS r
SET b.number = r.rownum
where b.id = r.id
--end query--

Comment: for this you have to create a new question for it and make it more clear with a nice example of what you are trying to do, and don't forget to assign my answer as accepted for this question :)...Thanks